# Call method from within itself?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, self-reference

I have this snippet:

```
myApp.factory('productsStore', function ($http, $q, Product) {
    var products = "";

    products = productsStore.get();

    return {
        get: function () {
            return Product.query({});
        }
    };
});
```

How can I call the `get()` method, from within the same 'factory'? `products = productsStore.get()` does not work obviously.

Comment: Declare `function get(){}`, then `return {get:get}`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow (you'll get what I mean soon enough)

Comment: @elclanrs: Make it an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *Revealing Module Pattern*:

```
myApp.factory('productsStore', function ($http, $q, Product) {
    var products = "";

    var get = function () {
        return Product.query({});
    };

    products = get();

    return {
        get: get
    };
});
```

Reasons I enjoy this pattern:

- No cluttering with `this.`, `MyObject.`, etc. prefixing.
- You see clearly in the bottom `return` what is publicly exposed.

A great article on the subject: [Mastering the Module Pattern](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the object you return to a variable, then call the get function defined in your variable, then return the variable.

Either that, or just duplicate your query code.